# action.callback function is not getting executed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-quickaction

I have a lightning component which is calling server-side apex code. Thes server-side code gets executed properly but setCallBack() function is not getting executed.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader, force:hasRecordId" controller = "serverController" >
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Yes" title="Yes" onclick="{! c.overwriteData }"/>
</aura:component>
```

**controller**

```
overwriteData: function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.renew");

    action.setParams({
        "RecordId" : component.get("v.recordId")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       console.log("Response -- " + response.getReturnValue());          
   });
   // Send action off to be executed
   $A.enqueueAction(action);

    helper.closeDialogue();
}
```

One thing I have noticed that the apex function gets executed after controller function execution complete (I checked developer console for that) and the console log or alert in set callback also do not get executed.

Comment: The helper.close dialogue should be within the call back if you want that to get executed after server response comes back

Comment: @RedDevil  It works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@redDevil's Comment on the question answered it:

> The helper.close dialogue should be within the call back if you want that to get executed after server response comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just directly checking console.log value, check status as well of response like below -

```
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //alert('recod got' +response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === 'INCOMPLETE') {
                console.log('You are offline.');    
            } else if (state === 'ERROR') {
                console.log('other error');
            }
        });
```